# Prestashop 1.7.6.1 URL get parameters

Tags: url, parameters, prestashop-1.7

I have a Whatsapp module on our website, that sends automatically the URL to us at the begining of the conversation.
I neeed in that URL to have also the serach parameter for the search page.

The code is

```
    $url ='';
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']))
            $url .=$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'];
        else
            $url .='http';
        $url .='://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
            $url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        
    }
    return $url;
```

The URL i get by whatsapp is:
http://www.incaltamintedame.ro/search?controller=search
and it should be
https://www.incaltamintedame.ro/search?controller=search&s=154001

Do you have any idea how can I fix it?
Thank you.